# Java Check workbook contains a specific spreadsheet or not using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using apache POI to create a excel file which contains multiple spreadsheet. Firstly, this method should check the workbook is empty or not after check its existence. If empty, create new sheet name "sheet1"; if not, check any sheets named "sheet1" in this workbook. If yes, adding new rows to the sheet; if not, create a sheet name "sheet1". Below is my current code, which I think is not the right method to achieve my goal:

```
    File file = new File("Main Data.xlsx");
    // Retrieve the workbook for the main report
    XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    // Check file existence 
    if (file.exists() == false) {
        // Create new file if it does not exist
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    } else {
        try ( 
            // Make current input to exist file
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
            }
    }
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet;
    // Check if the workbook is empty or not
    if (workbook.getNumberOfSheets() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
           if (workbook.getSheetName(i).equals(" Enc " + deviceLabel.getText() + " Info. ")) {
                spreadsheet = workbook.getSheet(" Enc " + deviceLabel.getText() + " Info. ");
            } else spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet(" Enc " + deviceLabel.getText() + " Info. ");
        }
    }
    else {
        // Create new sheet to the workbook if empty
        spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet(" Enc " + deviceLabel.getText() + " Info. ");
    }

    // Error here (variable spreadsheet may not have been initialized
    spreadsheet.shiftRows(0, spreadsheet.getLastRowNum(), 23);
```

Tow problems I am getting.

1. The for loop is obviously wrong to achieve my goal. Is there any way I can check empty spreadsheet or named spreadsheet exists already in the same time in one if statement?

e.g.

```
  if ((workbook.getNumberOfSheets() == 0) && !workbook.getSheet("sheet1").exists()) {
    workbook.createSheet("sheet1");
  } else workbook.getSheet("sheet1")
```

2. I keep getting error that said spreadsheet is not initialized, but if I delete the for loop, the error will disappear.

Comment: "The for loop is obviously wrong to achieve my goal." - It may be obvious to you, but it isn't obvious to us.

Comment: "I keep getting error that said spreadsheet is not initialized" - is that the exact error message?  If so, on which line?

Comment: @JoeC the for loop here may create multiple sheet if none of the exist sheet named "sheet1", which will be an error to create a sheet in a workbook.
And, I also comment the line has error which is the last line of my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured my problem with following code:

```
    File file = new File("Main Data.xlsx");
    // Retrieve the workbook for the main report
    XSSFWorkbook workbook;
    // Check file existence 
    if (file.exists() == false) {
        // Create new file if it does not exist
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    } else {
        try ( 
            // Make current input to exist file
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
            }
    }
    XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheet("sheet1");
    // Check if the workbook is empty or not
    if (workbook.getNumberOfSheets() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
           if (workbook.getSheetName(i).equals("sheet1")) {
                spreadsheet = workbook.getSheet("sheet1");
            } else spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");
        }
    }
    else {
        // Create new sheet to the workbook if empty
        spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");
    }

    // Shift rows down if exist
    spreadsheet.shiftRows(0, spreadsheet.getLastRowNum(), 23);
```

Comment: I see something wrong on your logic. You iterate over sheets and if you do not find the page you're looking for on the first try, you instantiate a new sheet. What if it is the second sheet?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply check  if a sheet is created or not with

```
workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName)
```

returns -1 if the sheet is not in the work book or Index if it is present in the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared workbook as final, it can not be initial for work!

Comment: I delete the final but nothing changed. It should have no effects to the spreadsheet.

Comment: You do not need a lot of code for purpose get a sheet. Just using this: 

`XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheet("sheet1");
 // Check if the workbook is empty or not
 if (spreadsheet == null) {
     // Create new sheet to the workbook if empty
     spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("sheet1");
 }`

Comment: Your code would work if the workbook is empty, while my case is the workbook may not be empty, it may already have a sheet name "sheet1". If it already exists, I cant create a new sheet with the same name.

Comment: On the code before, I have tried to get the sheet named "sheet1", if it not available then I create new. I do not create a duplicate sheet

Comment: I just figured out my problem with part of your ideas, I will upload my code as answer and reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your code is wrong a priori. You probably add pluses yourself for your answers?

```
public XSSFSheet factorySheet(final String name) {
         return Optional.ofNullable((XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheet(name))
                .orElseGet(()->(XSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet(name));
    }
```